# AngularJS masonry reload event not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-masonry

I am trying to update a masonry container when filters of my controller scope are changing with the following code.

```
$scope.toggleCardVisibility = function(cardType) {
    $scope.filters[cardType] = false === $scope.filters[cardType];

    $scope.$broadcast('masonry.reload');        
};
```

The elements in my HTML that are connected to the scope look like:

```
<div ng-show="$parent.filters.heart" class="card-wrapper">
    ...
</div>
```

`toggleCardVisibility` is called when clicking on a button by:

```
<button type="button" cardType="profileUpdate" class="btn btn-default selected" ng-click="toggleCardVisibility('profileUpdate');">
    ...
</button>
```

The problem is that this is not working as expected. The elements will be shown/hidden when calling the `toggleCardVisibility` function but the masonry container won't be updated. I assumed this could be a timing issue so I tried to exchange the first code snippet with the following one:

```
$scope.toggleCardVisibility = function(cardType) {
    $scope.filters[cardType] = false === $scope.filters[cardType];

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('masonry.reload');
    }, 1);
};
```

And now - the snippet with the timeout of 1ms works which is super annoying. Does anybody have a clue how to fix this issue?

The listener on for the `masonry.reload` event can be found in the vendor https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry/blob/master/angular-masonry.js.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker? I don't see where you call `toggleCardVisibility` or where you listen to `'masonry.reload'` events.

Comment: Unfortunately my angular app has a few dependencies that I can not really set up properly in plunkr. But I edited my post so that you can get a better insight of whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `$broadcast` to dispatches an event downwards to all child scopes, You have to notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

`$scope.$broadcast('masonry.reload');`

Should be:

`$rootScope.$broadcast('masonry.reload');`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope